# Python Function Return Statement is Confusing and Complex

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.x

Could any body explain what do the 'and' and 'or' statements are doing in the return statement of the function below ? 
the function seems to be returning the largest common denominator of a and b.

`def gcd(a,b): return b and gcd(b, a % b) or a`

Thank you !

Comment: Some good reading here: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html  This should explain the uses of `and` and `or` more in depth.

Comment: thank you so much your link was the most useful response ! i learned alot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing we can do is put in some parenthesis:

```
((b and gcd(b, a % b)) or a)
```

Now lets take this piece by piece:

```
b and gcd(b, a % b)
```

This will give `b` if `b` is falsy.  Otherwise it'll give you `gcd(b, a % b)`.  In other words, it's equivalent to the following conditional expression:

```
b if not b else gcd(b, a % b)
```

The next part of the expression is:

```
(...) or a
```

Which will give you `a` if the previous expression has a falsy result, otherwise it'll give you the previous expression.

Note that this *might* not be what you're expecting if you come from a language like `C` where boolean operations return booleans :-).  In python, the only boolean operation that is *guaranteed* to return a boolean is `not`.  This all tends to "just work" however because python knows how to get an object's "truth value" when it needs it.  e.g.:

```
if obj:
    ...
```

will actually check `bool(obj)` implicitly.

---

So, if I were to write out the whole thing using `if` suites, it would look like:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if not b:  # Likely `b == 0`.  This is the recursion base-case.
         val = b
    else:
         val = gcd(b, a % d)

    if val:
        return val
    else:
        return a
```

Answer (score 0):

The function continuously returns `gcd(b, a % b)` while `b` has a truthy value, i.e not equal to zero in this case.

When `b` reaches `0` (after consecutively being assigned to the result of `a % b`), `b and gcd(b, a % b)` will be `False` and the value of `a` will be returned.